# Can I use Cloud Build to perform CI/CD tasks in VM instances?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm using Google Cloud Platform and exploring its CI/CD tools.

I have an app deployed in a VM instance and I'm wondering if I can use GCP's tool such as Cloud Build to do CI/CD instead of using Jenkins.

From what I've learned over several resources, Cloud Build seems to be a nice tool for Cloud Run (deploying Docker images) and Cloud Functions.

Can I use it for apps deployed in VM instances?

When you create a job in Cloud Build, you set up a `cloudbuild.yaml` file in which you specify the build steps. How to write the step such that it will go into a linux VM, log in as a particular user, `cd` into a directory, pull the master branch of the project repo, and start running the `main.py` (say it's a python project)?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this like that

```
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    entrypoint: "bash"
    args:
      - "-c"
      - |
          gcloud compute ssh --zone us-central1-a my_user@oracle -- whoami;ls -la;echo "cool"
```

However, it's not a cloud native solution to deploy an app. The VM aren't "pets" but "cattle", that means, when you no longer need it, kill it, no emotion!

So, a modern way to use the cloud, is to create a new VM with the new version of your app. Optionally, you can keep the previous VM, stopped (to pay nothing) in case of rollback. To achieve this, you can add a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) which install all the required packages, libraries, and you app on the VM, and start it.

*An easiest way is to create a container. Like this, all the system dependencies are inside the container, and the VM doesn't need any customization: simply download the container and run it*

Cloud Build allows you creating a VM with a startup script with the gcloud CLI. You can also stop the previous one. Do you have a persistent to reuse (for the data between version)? with cloud build you can also clone it and attach it to the new VM; or detach it from the previous one and attach it to the new one!